# Purchase SendGrid Twilio Email Activity Feed API when using Azure Resource Groups

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I want to be able to see the status and activity of an email through SendGrid API. There is a help page for [getting started with the Email Activity Feed API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api/) however it says i need to purchase history. Purchasing is controlled through the Azure web portal which has completely different pricing tiers from the normal SendGrid portal. It also has no option for purchasing the Activity History as the documentation indicates i should do.

I've tried making the purchase through the SendGrid Portal, but it seems to be blocked for my account. It says "You don't have permissions to view this page. You can request access from your account administrator." even though I created this resource.

Is this API even available to Azure users?

Comment: If anyone is wondering, I contacted Azure Support and they said i can't do this if I purchased through the tenant instead of through Twilio SendGrid.

I ended up making an Azure Function so that SendGrid can post to it and write the Email Activity logs to an Azure SQL Server.